# Peace Domain Cleric's Protecting Bond feature: Can you reduce/negate the damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, damage, damage-resistance, damage-reduction

I was reading up this new subclass's feature which reads:

> The bond you forge between people helps them protect each other. When a creature affected by your Emboldening Bond feature is about to take damage, a second bonded creature within 30 feet of the first can use its reaction to teleport to an unoccupied space within 5 feet of the first creature. The second creature then takes **all** the damage instead.

(emphasis mine)

Now I know that usually when damage can't be reduced or bypasses resistances, it is explicitly stated. However I'm uncertain if it has ever been stated in this way. Is this just a verbose way of saying the second creature takes the damage, or does it really take **all** the damage?

If it bypasses resistances and immunities, what about temporary hit points? could it be reduced or negated by magic (something like Resilient Sphere)?

(Note: Resilient sphere would not apply based on the spell's limitations, as teleporting woul displace you out of it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## You can reduce/negate the damage.

As you said, when damage can't be reduced or negated, it is explicitly stated.

> This damaged can't be reduced or negated in any way.

The verbiage here is simply to distinguish from effects where you can affect only part of the damage, like the Interception Fighting Style or the Parry Maneuver:

> [...] you can use your reaction to reduce the damage the target takes by 1d10 + your proficiency bonus [...]

> [...] you can use your reaction and expend one superiority die to reduce the damage by the number you roll on your superiority die + your Dexterity modifier

So basically all the damage that you protected your target from, is transferred to you. If it's from a Frost Brand dealing slashing and cold damage, then all that damage is taken by you. If you're resistant to that, great, half damage taken. If you have temporary hit points, great, no damage to actual HP.